# Disable the "Stacked" option in "multiBarChart" "rChart"

Tags: r, rcharts

How can I disable the `Stacked` option in a `multiBarChart` produced by `rCharts`.

```
data <- data.frame(Var = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   Fac1 = rep(c("A" ,"B"), 2),
                   Fac2 = rep(c("Blue", "Red"), each=2))

require(rCharts)    

n1 <- nPlot(Var ~ Fac2, group = "Fac1", data = data, type = "multiBarChart")
n1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n1$chart(showControls = FALSE)
```